# PHP MySQL query to array help

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to pull a query like this one

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT id, bid, text, link, orderid  
FROM blast_sl 
WHERE buuid = $bid 
ORDER BY orderid");

returns:
1,1,test1,http://test1.com,1
2,1,test2,http://test2.com,2
```

What I need is a little more advanced then

```
mysql_fetch_array
```

So when this query runs it will populate different spots on a page. I won't be able to run any loops in the page, so I need them setup like this.

```
$result[1][3] 

so $result [orderid][text]
```

This would pull the first row first item..

```
test1

and $result[2][3]
```

would pull

```
test2
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to fetch the data into one huge result array:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT id, bid, text, link, orderid  
FROM blast_sl 
WHERE buuid = $bid 
ORDER BY orderid");

$results=array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $results[$row[0]]=$row;
    // Uncomment next line to make $result[1][3] return 3rd rather than 4th item
    // array_unshift($results[$row[0]],''); // Adds a dummy value at the start of the array
}
$result=$results; //copy back into the $result var
```

and you should be good to go. Remember that the arrays will be 0 indexed rather than 1. If you really need `$result[1][3]` to return the 3rd element rather than the 4th, you'll need to do some fancy looping and counting to get it sorted

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
   $data[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

Would give you

```
$data = array(
    1 => array('id' => 1, 'bid' => 1, 'text' => 'test1', 'link' => 'http://test1.com', 'orderid' => 1,
    2 => array('id' => 2, .....),
    ...
)
```

You can build up that array any way you want, this is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the argument `MYSQL_NUM` into the `mysql_fetch_array` function, this would allow you to reference the record columns by index.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
```

Then, to create the array

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $result [] =  $row;  
 }

$result[2][3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
mysql_query("SELECT orderid, text FROM blast_sl ORDER BY orderid");
```

Sorry if it isn't, but I'm not very sure about what you want.